# What subquery can I use to filter data depending on strings?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I have created the following tables:

```
create table Person (

    id_person int,
    name varchar(255),
    primary key (id_person)
);

create table Picture (

    id_picture int,
    id_person int,
    country varchar(255),    //Shows in what country the picture has been taken
    primary key(id_picture),
    foreign key (id_person) references Person (id_person)
);
```

I want to execute a `SELECT` clause that filters the persons that just have taken pictures on the `UK` and in `SPAIN`. Not in other countries.

For example:

Table person

```
   id       name
-------------------
   1        Andrew
   2        Javi
   3        Kevin
```

Table picture

```
   id_picture      id_person      country
------------------------------------------------
      1               1           BELGIUM
      2               3           USA
      3               1           UK
      4               2           UK
      5               3           NORWAY
      6               2           SPAIN
      7               1           USA
      8               2           UK
      9               3           DENMARK
```

As the tables show, just the `Person` with the `id_person = 2` has taken pictures just in `UK` and `SPAIN`.

How can I show the `Persons` that has taken pictures just on `UK` AND (not OR) `SPAIN`?

Following the example above, the output I would like to get would be:

```
    id_person      name
-------------------------------
      2            Javi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like below using distinct count()

```
select id_person,name from person p join picture p1 on p.id=p1.id_person
 where country in ('uk','spain')
 group by id_person,name
having count(distinct country)=2
```